# Is there any way to add more UDIDs when I have more than 100 devices on my iOS developer account?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

If we want to add more UDIDs when we buy more than 100 devices, how can we do that? Does Apple make it easier? I do not want to get a enterprise license. Can I handle this with the current account?

Comment: Your devices list will reset once per year when your membership renews.  You cannot add more than 100 devices per year.  If you want to test with more people you should use TestFlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add UDIDs to apple developer account for allowing those devices to install your app no there is no way you can get more than 100 devices registered with single developer account, and I guess that is more than a developer needs even if you own an MNC

if you need to test your apps on actual devices and you have around 1000 devices with you then you have an option to use testflight instead, testlight allows you to invite 2000 testers who can continue testing until 60 days.

And you dont need UDIDs for that just email accounts